# LIBGDX Very huge memory leak at Asset Manager

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, libgdx

I make game on LIBGDX. I have assets folder which takes 8 mb. There are many texture atlases in the folder. When I'm loading my assets in Asset Manager, 
free RAM immediately decreases by 700 MB. This is what phones shows itselfs. 
In Android profiler (Android monitor) in AS i can see that the game (Graphics) takes 760 MB of memory. But when I launch the game with Android Device Manager,  I see the following numbers: heap size: 14, highlighted: 7 in the "heap" tab. How is this possible? Thank you all for your reply.

Comment: I mean, ADM does not see that my game takes 700 mb, not 14.

Comment: You have to add some code, if you have a for-loop somewhere that reloads it that could be a reason. Create an MCVE